# Addition of two lists with same asset number

Tags: python, list

I have the following lists below and would like to sum up the asset values that have the same asset number so that I can get something similar to below

```
Asset number Total
11230202     10500.5
11230101     79
11230213     0
11230228     0
```

**Asset number list:**

> [u' 11230202 ', u' 11230101 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230213 ', u'
>   11230202 ', u' 11230232 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230202
>   ', u' 11230101 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230228 ', u'
>   11230202 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230101
>   ']

**Asset value list:**

> [10000.0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 69]

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
s = map(int, [u' 11230202 ', u' 11230101 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230213 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230232 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230101 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230228 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230202 ', u' 11230101 '])
s1 = [10000.0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 69]
d = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in zip(s, s1):
   d[a].append(b)

final_d = {a:sum(b) for a, b in d.items()}
for a, b in sorted(final_d.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1], reverse=True):
   print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
(11230202, 10500.5)
(11230101, 79)
(11230232, 0)
(11230228, 0)
(11230213, 0)
```